# Necesito ir guardando distintos resultados de una misma formula

Tags: java, eclipse

Hola buenas tardes soy nuevo en esto y pues para un proyecto de universidad me vi en la necesidad de aprender un poco de programación basica. pegare el script y luego relatare lo que necesito.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModosNormales {
    public static void main(String[] ar) {
        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
        int nx,ny,c,n;
        float lx;
        float ly;

    float fn;
    c=172;

    System.out.print("Ingrese valor de nx:");
    nx=teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Ingrese valor de ny:");
    ny=teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Ingrese lx:");
    lx=teclado.nextFloat();
    System.out.print("Ingrese ly:");
    ly=teclado.nextFloat();
    fn=c*(float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((nx/lx),2)+(float)(Math.pow((ny/ly),2)));

    System.out.print("Fn=");
    System.out.println(fn);

    for(n=1;n>0;n++) { 

    int nx1,ny1;
    float fn1;


       System.out.print("Ingrese valor de nx:");
       nx1=teclado.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Ingrese valor de ny:");
       ny1=teclado.nextInt();
       fn1=c*(float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((nx1/lx),2)+(float)(Math.pow((ny1/ly),2)));
       System.out.print("Fn=");
       System.out.println(fn1);



       if(fn1>=500)
    {System.out.println("Frecuencia mayor o igual a 500Hz"); break;





}}}}
```

Necesito saber cuantos "fn1" se repiten ya que cada "fn1" es distinto resultado porque acá..

fn1=c*(float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((nx1/lx),2)+(float)(Math.pow((ny1/ly),2)));   Varian los Nx1...lx...etc

entonce me dan distintos "fn1" entonces como puedo hacer para que eso se guarde y me diga cuantos fn1 se repiten ? nose si me explique bien ya que soy novato en esto. se los agradeceria

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para empezar, el código no está muy bien escrito. No entiendo muy bien como usas el for. De todas formas, una solución que se me ocurre es que crees un array de elementos, en este caso de tipo float, y guardes los distintos valores en él. Imagínate que quieres 10 fn1

```
for(n=0;n<10;n++) { 

int nx1,ny1;
float[10] fn1;


   System.out.print("Ingrese valor de nx:");
   nx1=teclado.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Ingrese valor de ny:");
   ny1=teclado.nextInt();
   fn1[n]=c*(float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((nx1/lx),2)+(float)(Math.pow((ny1/ly),2))); //en cada posición del array guardas un valor de fn1
   System.out.print("Fn=");
   System.out.println(fn1[n]);


}
```

Para saber cuántos se repiten, puedes recorrer el array de la siguiente forma:

```
int aux = 0;

for (int i=0;i<fn1.length-1;i++)
 {
      if (fn1[i] = fn1[i+1])
 {
    aux++; //si el elemento actual es igual al siguiente, incrementamos la variable aux
  }
}
```

Si el número de elementos es variable, entonces esto se puede implementar con un ArrayList:

```
for(n=0;n<10;n++) { 

int nx1,ny1;
ArrayList<float> fn1= new ArrayList<>();


   System.out.print("Ingrese valor de nx:");
   nx1=teclado.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Ingrese valor de ny:");
   ny1=teclado.nextInt();
   fn1.add(n,c*(float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((nx1/lx),2)+(float))(Math.pow((ny1/ly),2))); //en cada posición del array guardas un valor de fn1
   System.out.print("Fn=");
   System.out.println(fn1.get(n));


}


for (int i=0;i<fn1.size()-1;i++)
 {
      if (fn1.get(i) = fn1.get(i+1))
 {
    aux++; //si el elemento actual es igual al siguiente, incrementamos la variable aux
  }
}
```

Comment: Si perdón por no escribirlo bien como dije soy novato y por necesidad tuve que hacer esto, gracias pero.. por ejemplo si los fn1 varian en cuanto a cantidad pueden ser 30...21...4...5 nose. en ese caso si es variable como se hace ?

Comment: los fn1 son el resultado de realizar la operación c*(float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((nx1/lx),2)+(float)(Math.pow((ny1/ly),2))). En cada uno de los elementos del array (en este caso de 10 elementos), se almacena un valor distinto para fn1. Para acceder a cualquiera de estos resultados tienes que hacer fn1[n], siendo n la posición a la que quieres acceder. Te recomiendo leer la documentación de java para ver cómo funcionan los arrays: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: intentare a ver como me va y leere el documento. muchas gracias kalia por tu ayuda

Comment: @MatiasRetamales si lo que te refieres es a que pueden variar en tamaño, es decir, no son siempre 10 elementos por ejemplo, entonces puedes usar los ArrayList, que son estructuras dinámicas, al contrario que los arrays.

Comment: Variar en numeros ya que depende de la medida de la sala en el caso de lo que yo quiero hacer por ejemplo una sala de 10x3 puede tener cierta cantidad de fn1

Comment: @MatiasRetamales he editado la pregunta implementándolo con un ArrayList, de forma que el número de elementos puede ser variable. Por favor, si mi respuesta te fue útil, considera darme un voto positivo :)

Comment: Así será kalia ya te vote :) mira me sale esto aca

Comment: veras mira aca    -    -   -  ArrayList<float> fn1= new ArrayList<>    Me sale: "Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete ReferenceType"  Que debo hacer ?

Comment: @MatiasRetamales Perdona, es ArrayList <float> fn1 = new ArrayList<>(); Añade los dos paréntesis al final, disculpa.